# Pre-Trained models for text Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, text-classification, pre-trained-model

So I have few words without labels but I need to classify them into 4-5 categories.
I can visibly say that this test set can be classified. Although I do not have training data so I need to use a pre-trained model to classify these words. Which model is good for this paradigm and on which dataset has it already been trained?

Thanks

Comment: Into which categories?

Comment: categories like artifacts, animals, food and birds(if you may)

Comment: Unless the data comes from some well known dataset, there's very little chance you'll find a pre-trained model specific to your data and categories. You could try clustering, but it won't produce exactly the categories that you expect.

Answer (score 9):

The task we are taking about is called Zero-Shot Topic Classification - predicting a topic that the model has not been trained on. This paradigm is supported by Hugging Face library, you can read more [here](https://huggingface.co/zero-shot/). The most common pre-trained model is Bart Large MNLI - the checkpoint for [bart-large](https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large) after being trained on the [MNLI dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/multi_nli).
Here is a simple example, showing the classification of phrase "I like hot dogs" without any preliminary training:

1. First of all, please install the transformers library:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade transformers
   ```
2. Then import and initialize the pipeline:

   ```
   from transformers import pipeline

   classifier = pipeline('zero-shot-classification', model='facebook/bart-large-mnli')
   ```
3. Enter our toy dataset:

   ```
    labels = ["artifacts", "animals", "food", "birds"]
    hypothesis_template = 'This text is about {}.'
    sequence = "I like hot dogs"
   ```
4. Predict the label:

   ```
   prediction = classifier(sequence, labels, hypothesis_template=hypothesis_template, multi_class=True)

   print(prediction)
   ```

The output will be somethng like

```
`{'sequence': 'i like hot dogs', 
'labels': ['food', 'animals', 'artifacts', 'birds'], 
'scores': [0.9971900582313538, 0.00529429130256176, 0.0020991512574255466, 
0.00023589911870658398]}`
```

It can be interpreted, that the model assigns the highest probability (0.997..) to the label 'food', which is the correct answer.